# Failsafe method with Python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

Lets say I have a method `method1()` which has a blocking HTTP request using `urllib`.

Say if this HTTP request doesn't return within `3 seconds` I want to stop this and return a different method's value, say `method2()`. How can this be done?

Comment: Threads and event loops often have a timeout option. That would be where I'd look.

Comment: Since you've tagged your question [python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-requests/info) see the `requests` documentation for passing a [`timeout`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the `timeout` for your [urllib request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) in the optional parameter timeout.

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None, [timeout, ]*, cafile=None,
    capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)
```

Where you can pass the time value in the timeout parameter, you can do other functions according to the data you get.

Comment: Note that a `URLError` isn't by itself proof of a timeout.

Comment: I think there can others causes for URLError as well, but may not be a good way to check for timeout here.

Comment: The OP would need to check the `URLError`'s `reason` attribute which should be something like `'<urlopen error timed out>'`.